# EC2 instance type for MySql database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

Not using RDS and using barebone EC2 instance for mysql. Is it beneficial to use I or D type instance when using EBS for data storage? What I have understood is I and D instance come with instance storage which is optimized. But if you are not going to use instance storage is there even a point of using I or D type instance?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using instance storage for RDS.  Instance storage is ephemeral and will be lost if an instance dies.

Comment: yes, the question is about using EBS not instance storage.